# Confirming User Email with Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'd like to confirm a user's email using Cloud Code. The problem is I don't want to use Parse's method, being that you can only customize the text and not the email itself.

I'm looking for a way to generate my own "confirm email" link similar to how Parse does it, and use cloud code to send an email through send grid (a customized email), etc. Does anyone know how to get started with generating the link?

I know how to generate a session token and username, but other than that I'm a bit stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the emails and password reset page, etc. Check out this blog post for a bit more info: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/express-your-brand-with-parse/

Comment: Thanks Jake. Unfortunately we've already done that. What we want is to customize the email confirmation and password reset emails (with our company banner, some useful tips, etc). The only thing we can do for now is customize the text of the email, but we want to customize the look as well.